# How can I verify the web page response using snmp?

Tags: linux, snmp

I have just started to learn snmp protocols and notably centreon program and I need to find out how can a verify a web-page response or a web-service (in HTTP simple mode).

The only sourse I have found for a moment is this one https://documentation-fr.centreon.com/docs/plugins-packs/fr/1.x/catalog.html where it says "App-Protocol-HTTP, a model to supervise an HTTP server".

I wonder what that suppose to mean? Is it somehow linked to a snmp protocol or not at all?

Comment: SNMP is not designed to check HTTP responses. Wrong tool for the task!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Centreon can collect information on various systems using SNMP, that's true.

But Centreon plugins can add other methods for collecting information. In particular, App-Protocol-HTTP adds the ability to make HTTP queries and check for:

- response time
- presence of a specific string in a HTTP response
- presence of specific SOAP or JSON content

This has nothing to do with SNMP. With plugins, Centreon can and will do *more* than just SNMP.